# nicematrix set name by pgfkey - expanding problem?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, nicematrix

Once again I need help with my `gaussenv` macro. This time, since the names of the pictures drawn by `nicematrix` have to be different. Therefore, I thought I'd create a numeric pgfkey which holds some kind of index of the current matrix.

And this is with which I came up:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfkeys{
        /tikz/gaussenv/.cd,
        niceMatrixName/.initial=1,
}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/gaussenv/niceMatrixName}matrix

\begin{align*}
        \begin{pNiceMatrix}[name={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/gaussenv/niceMatrixName} matrix}]
                1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
                3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
        \end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{align*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw (1 matrix-1-1) -- (1 matrix-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But sadly when compiling tikz does not know the nodes `1 matrix-1-1` or `1 matrix-2-2`, but if I use `\begin{pNiceMatrix}[name={1 matrix}]` as environment declaration, if works.

I guess it has something to do with expanding, but I don't know how to solve this and even if it is really because of expanding.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your MWE is not complete. You have not loaded `nicematrix` nor `tikz`.

Comment: Corrected that one

Comment: As you have suggested, the value of the key `name` is not expanded and that's why you can't do that.

Comment: Do yout know, wether there is a way to expand it properly (or work around this?) Sadly I cannot use the `\NiceMatrixLastEnv` because of my version of `nicematrix`)

Comment: I can give a line of code which will define `\NiceMatrixLastEnv` for your version of `nicematrix`. I don't want to put it on this site because it uses internals of the package (LaTeX3 says these internals should be used only in the package). Send me an email: fpantigny@wanadoo.fr

Comment: Does work now, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of giving a name to each environment of `nicematrix`, you should access to the PGF/Tikz nodes created by `nicematrix` directly by their names. These names use the number of the environment given by `\NiceMatrixLastEnv` (available in versions ≥ 3.9 2020-01-10).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
        \begin{pNiceMatrix}
                1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
                3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
        \end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,name prefix = nm-\NiceMatrixLastEnv-]
  \draw (1-1) -- (2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: Well done! A very clever solution :).